# Convert String to double

Tags: android, parsing, numberformatexception

Is there way to convert a string to double. This is how i did.

```
String s = b.getText().toString();
       double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

It gives NumberFormatException

Comment: What value was returned from `getText()`?

Comment: What does b contain for text?

Comment: Debug and check what is value of s , which is being passed in parseDouble

Comment: the value of 's' is entered by the user..but before that itself the exception occurs

Answer (score 3):

Try this

String s = b.getText().toString();
double d = Double.valueOf(s.trim()).doubleValue();

Comment: What is the value of s i.e. b.getText().toString()?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably starting off with a zero-length string. Check the length before you parse it. It also wouldn't hurt to catch NumberFormatException, although that shouldn't be problem if you have `android:inputType="number"` in the view's layout.

```
double d = 0;
CharSequence cs = b.getText();
if(cs != null && cs.length() > 0) {
    d = Double.parseDouble(cs.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar problem.
for correct formatting EditText text content to double value i use this code:

```
try {
        String eAm = etAmount.getText().toString();
        DecimalFormat dF = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        Number num = dF.parse(eAm);
        mPayContext.amount = num.doubleValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mPayContext.amount = 0.0d;
    }
```

this is independet from current phone locale and return correct double value.

hope it's help;